# What's the best practice for including Powershell in a C# application?

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

I've gotten my application up and running but it doesn't seem to want to install correctly via  ClickOnce. It uses Powershell and I've included the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.DLL, Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Native.DLL and the System.Management.Automation.DLL in my Application Files. I've tried all of them every which way (Include, Prerequisite, Excluded). I also have them copied manually in my references by copying them out of the GAC and into that folder. In addition, I have them set to copy local.

For that, I followed several instructions that told me I should change the References in my csproj file to:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure"/>
```

for each of the references. That way it would actually look for the latest DLLs on the computer.

The problem is that if they're set to prereqs, I get a message telling me they should be installed in the GAC, first. If they're set to include, I believe it copies the files, lets my application run, but I get...

> "An error occured when loading the system Windows PowerShell Snap-Ins.
>   Please contact Microsoft Support Services."

Now, I've narrowed it down to different versions of Powershell or the Automations dlls on different computers. The entire application works fine on my computer, but not on (some) others.

So! I don't know if I've given too much detail, but what I'd like to have happen is for my application to simply copy the required DLLs or reference ones that are already there (preferably the latter).

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

These files are installed by PowerShell.  You do not want to install them with your app.  The installer you're using should provide a way to "exclude" these dependencies.  You're best bet would be to check for the version of PowerShell you require as a custom action and then alert the user if they don't have to appropriate version of PowerShell.

Comment: Would there be a way to use whatever their version of PowerShell is? The problem I'm having is that regardless, it always looks for my version. I noticed tonight that my application works on any Windows 8 computer, but not 7, Vista or XP. I thought that... 

<Reference Include="Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure"/>

...without the extra details would look for their version instead of the one I've flagged.

Comment: On Windows 8, PowerShell 3.0 is the default. Check the version of System.Management.Automation you're project is referencing.  If it is 3.0, then your users will need PowerShell 3.0. I'm not sure about Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure but I think it might be only for PowerShell 3.0 (it is compiled against .NET 4.0). In this case, your installer should check for WMF 3.0 installed on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 SP2/R2 SP1.  It isn't supported on Vista or XP. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

Comment: I suppose for now I can include WMF 3.0, for now, but what about in the future? Say the next version of Powershell doesn't support 7. Obviously I want to keep 7 support for a while (a lot of people will use it for a long time). Is there still no way to have my application only reference whatever version of Powershell they have?

Comment: Officially, no.  Products like Exhange Server IIRC even require PowerShell/WMF as an installation prereq.  Some folks have been able to pick out all the individual pieces their program needed but that approach is fraught with peril IMO.

Comment: Okay. So I guess I just shouldn't believe everything I see on the internet :P Thanks! I'll just make my application Windows 7 + 8 compatible, for now at least.